# Why does it appear that my system is designed to PREVENT me from connecting the washing machine to mains water?

Tags: water, washing-machine, valve

My plumber, who is really into his engineering has installed brand new plumbing in my kitchen. The endpoint valves for washing machine and dishwasher are "non return" valves.

Both of these valves have some sort of a "button" inside. When the valves are open and water is flowing, pushing that button stops the flow.

- Why is this there?

On the other side, the water-in hose that came with my washing machine has a "rod" inside, which is clearly designed to push the "button" inside the valve...

- Why is that there?

Basically, it feels like the hose and the valve were designed in some way to interface with each other and prevent me from doing what I am trying to do (get water into my washing machine)

- What am I doing wrong and can I adjust my system to work for me?

[image]

Comment: The device purpose is to prevent backflow. Last answer is more suitable.

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: Attach a picture of the other end of the supply hose. Maybe if you connect the other end of the hose to the supply valve, the water would flow.

Comment: Or try removing the filter screen and cutting away most of that gripping tab so it does not contact the check-valve in the cut-off valve.

Answer (score 6):

Some washing machine supply hoses incorporate a special valve designed to shut off the flow In the event of a rupture in the hose. One brand with this feature is Flood-Safe. If you carefully examine your hose, you should be able determine if yours is that type.

Such hoses have a restriction at the washing machine end and a spring loaded shutoff valve in the end connected to the house supply. In normal operation these hoses fill the washer at a significantly slower rate than a standard hose. I installed a set of these for an elderly neighbor and he could not tolerate the slower fill. I had to replace them with standard supply hoses.

These special hoses are also available for toilet supply lines, and maybe other applications.

These rupture detecting hoses can be troublesome. When turning on the water at the cutoff valve, one must operate the valve slowly or the valve in the hose will seal shut.

Standard washing machine supply hoses are non-directional, but the rupture shut-off type must be installed with the valve end on the supply.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the valve in the picture will the water flow out?  If it does then you only have to connect the hose to the valve's outlet. If no water flows out when the valve is opened then the valve is installed backward. This is a valve with a built in check valve or backflow preventer to stop any water from flowing into your water system and contaminating it in the event of a drop in the supply pressure. This is a common device that I have seen in commercial buildings.

Comment: as I said: "When the valves are open and water is flowing, pushing that button stops the flow.". In other words: when the hose is not connected, water flows, when the hose IS connected (obviously that's the first thing I tried?...), water does not flow...

Comment: Washer supply lines in the US are continually pressurized. The control valves are inside the washing machine. Rupture of washing machine fexible supply lines is one of the most common causes of flooding from plumbing leaks in the US.

Comment: It could be that you have flexible supply hoses that are intended for a different application. Your valves may have a check valve and the internal fitting is simply pressing a check valve closed. What does the other end of the supply hose look like? Can you install the supply hoses the other way round? Are there instructions?

Comment: @JimStewart the common washing machine/dishwasher connection in the UK also uses a pressurised hose, with the control valve in the machine

Comment: It’s a legal requirement in the UK to have double check valves installed to stop back flow, maybe legal is the wrong word but without in the UK you won’t be compliant with building regs.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know / can see the "rod" in the washing machines hose is just there so you can remove the sieve[1], which is there to keep rust particles etc. from entering the hose/machine.

I'm pretty sure it's definitely not designed to push that "button" in the valve. I fact it looks to me like two designs interacting with each other which were never intended to.

-> Take a look in the manual of the machine/hose to verify the "rod" is there to remove the sieve and/or remove the sieve temporarily to test if it works without.

-> Add a small extension/spacer pipe piece (or however one would call that in English) to keep the two parts from interfering or mutilate the sieve+rod (cut the rod).

[1] some hose sieve images: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=washing+machine+hose+sieve&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 0):

The pipe connectors have the "rod" you describe to push open the valve in the shutoff tap supplied by the plumber.

Connected together correctly, the water flows as the washing machine demands water (controlled valves inside).